# Gulp Task throwing "Did you forget to signal async completion?" due to different webpack-stream setups

Tags: webpack, gulp

I have 2 almost identical build tasks: "build:dev" and "build:prod" they both inject a version number into the code and builds using webpack-stream, refering to 2 different webpack setups. The "build:prod" task fails and throws the "Did you forget to signal async completion" even when I return the stream. "Build:dev" seems to work fine even though it has the same signature - only difference seems to be the refered webpack file. I can get it to work by using a complete callback - but other tasks (version bumping) will then not work as intended. 
Both webpack files included in full length as it seems to be the source of the error.

```
// gulpfile.js
const webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.prod');
const webpackDevConfig = require('./webpack.dev');
const bump = require('gulp-bump');
const injectVersion = require('gulp-inject-version');
//[...]
gulp.task('build:prod', () => {
    return gulp.src('./src/app.js')
        .pipe(injectVersion({
            package_file: './config.json'
        }))
        .pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
})

gulp.task('build:dev', () => {
    return gulp.src('./src/app.js')
        .pipe(injectVersion({
            package_file: './config.json'
        }))
        .pipe(webpackStream(webpackDevConfig))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
})
```

```
//webpack.prod.js
const path = require('path');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',

    entry: ["@babel/polyfill", "./src/app.js"],
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: [/(node_modules)/,
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'browser.js'),
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'bootstrap.js') 
            ],
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader' ,
                options: { 
                    presets: ['@babel/preset-env']
                  }

            }
        }]
    },
    optimization: {
        minimizer: [
            new UglifyJsPlugin({
                uglifyOptions: {
                    compress: {
                        warnings: false,
                        drop_console: true
                    },
                    output: {
                        comments: false,
                        beautify: false
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'bundleprod.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/dist')
    }
};
```

```
//webpack.dev.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',

    watch: true,
    entry: ["./src/app.js"],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: [/(node_modules)/, 
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'browser.js'), 
                        path.resolve(__dirname, 'bootstrap.js')],
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
            }
        ]
    },
    devtool: "eval-source-map"/* 'eval-source-map' */,
    output: {
        filename:   "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname + "/dist") 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accepting the `done` callback function as an argument to your `build:prod` task but you are not ever calling it.

Change this:

```
gulp.task('build:prod', (done) => { ... }
```

...to this:

```
gulp.task('build:prod', () => { ... }
```

Gulp will check the number of arguments to your task function and, if you are taking the `done` callback, it will expect you to call it to signal completion.

Comment: The done function was not intended to be part of the code example sorry. If I call done() the function will complete too early without assuring that the stream has actually completed. If I remove the done argument I still get the error, so I still think that the error somehow has to do with the different webpack setups. Have removed the done argument..,.

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the `.pipe(webpackStream(webpackConfig))` line?

Comment: Yes that works. It also works if I pass the webpackDevConfig instead. But does not solve the actual problem of course.

Comment: If the dev config works then perhaps start with that and start adding bits of the prod config until it stops working. Then we'll know which part is causing the problem.